# Process reg query with spaces

Tags: batch-file, registry

I’m trying to read a registry key value and use it within a variable latter on in the program however my registry key contains spaces and now I cant get it to work, dose anybody know hoe to process keys with spaces?

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Software\VTS\TREADSTONE LT\Main" /v EXECUTE ^| find /i "REG_SZ"') do set UserNm=%%a 

MSG * %UserNm%
pause
```

I'm using Windows batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use double quotes you need to use `usebackq` in your `for` loop and change your `'`'s to back ticks.

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=3" %%a in (`reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Software\VTS\TREADSTONE LT\Main" /v EXECUTE ^| find /i "REG_SZ"`) do set UserNm=%%a
```

Comment: for /f "usebackq tokens=3" %%a in (`reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Software\VTS\TREADSTONE LT\Main" /v EXECUTE ^| find /i "REG_SZ"`) do set ACADVER=%%a 

msg * %ACADVER%

Comment: Didnt work checked the key manually in the regestry andit says C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD Architecture 2012\acad.exe

Comment: How didn't it work? Did you get an error? It works fine for me.

Comment: nope I just still get C:\oohhh sory it dose I just havent caterd for the spaces in the name my fault, do you know how to cater for the spaces in the name (red faced, lol)

Comment: No worries, do you mean the spaces in the value?

Comment: Yeah the spaces in the value.

Comment: I had a play around with it and you need to use more tokens. Just change `tokens=3` to `tokens=3*"` and then use `%%a %%b %%c` etc to get any tokens after the space. i.e. `set UserNm=%%a %%b %%c`

Comment: for /f "usebackq tokens=3*" %%a %%b %%c in (`reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Software\VTS\TREADSTONE LT\Main" /v EXECUTE ^| find /i "REG_SZ"`) do set ACADVER=%%a %%b %%c


msg * "%ACADVER%"

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer, use only one token when declaring it, but use multiple when setting it `for /f "usebackq tokens=3*" %%a in (reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Software\VTS\TREADSTONE LT\Main" /v EXECUTE ^| find /i "REG_SZ") do set ACADVER=%%a %%b %%c` - remember to use the backticks, which won't show up in my comment as SO removes them thinking they are to highlight code.